# Getting elapsed time using monotonic() in seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a timestamp (as a string), I want to output the elapsed time in seconds using `monotonic()` in Python 3.6.

I've tried:

```
task_start = '1510150124.133201'
[long running code]
time_taken = time.monotonic() - float(task_start) # -1510132274.84085
```

However, this gives a negative value i.e. `-1510132274.84085` not the elapsed time in seconds, why?

Comment: Where does this string value for `task_start` come from. Why not `task_start = time.monotonic()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of consecutive calls is valid.

Thats what the python docs say. Since your `task_start` variable is not called with `time.monotonic()` it is not working.